# Using fbi - No such file or directory

Tags: pi-zero, fbi

I installed fbi on my Raspberry Pi Zero and I'm trying to display a picture using

```
sudo fbi -T 2 -d /dev/fb1 - noverbose -a testpic1.jpg
```

It then displays a black screen with

```
Open testpic1.jpg: No such file or directory
```

The picture is in the Pictures folder, I'm not sure if that's the right place to put it. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I'm using a 3.5 inch lcd that plugs into the gpio pins, not an hdmi connection, if that changes anything.

Comment: Did you try using the full path to the file?   /home/pi/Pictures/testpic1.jpg. ?

Comment: When I try that a black screen comes up that says `/home/pi/Pictures/testpic1.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out I just needed to enter

```
sudo fbi -T 2 -d /dev/fb0 -noverbose /home/pi/Pictures/testpic1.jpg
```